excel vba test a value if exist from sheet1(carnet) in sheet2(stock) and return it in sheet3(liste)
i have made this code and when i test the if statement by this condition below it works
`If crnt.Range("E" & i).Value <> stk.Range("A" & i).Value Then`

...but when i change the operator to equal as showen in the if statement in the for loop it doesnt work
i can provide the macro file if someone likes to help me.
Sub total() 
    Dim ttl, i, j As Integer 
    Dim wb As Workbook 
    Dim stk, crnt, lst As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set stk = wb.Sheets("stock")
    Set crnt = wb.Sheets("Tabelle1")
    Set lst = wb.Sheets("liste")
    ttl = Sheets("Tabelle1").UsedRange.Rows.Count 
    ttls = Sheets("stock").UsedRange.Rows.Count 
    'MsgBox "total carnet : " & ttl & " et stock : " & ttls 
    'MsgBox stk.Range("A4").Value
    
    'treatement
    
    'lst.Range("A2").Value = stk.Range("A2").Value
    'lst.Range("B2").Value = stk.Range("E2").Value 
    'lst.Range("C2").Value = stk.Range("D2").Value
    
    'test of values
    MsgBox stk.Range("A2").Value
    MsgBox crnt.Range("E2").Value
    'loop
    For i = 2 To ttl
        If crnt.Range("E" & i).Value = stk.Range("A" & i).Value Then
            lst.Range("A" & i).Value = stk.Range("A" & i).Value
            lst.Range("B" & i).Value = stk.Range("E" & i).Value
            lst.Range("C" & i).Value = stk.Range("D" & i).Value
        End If 
    lst.Select
    End Sub
    Next i

i tried all my effort to understand where is the problem and why i cant run this macro
please if someone has an idea about the problem will explain me.
thank you so much in advance

Just some hints: a) you can't include a sub procedure within other code statements, e.g. If ... Then (where is End If?) b) You have an "outsourced"Next i after the closingEnd Sub, it should belong within the Sub proc (before lst.Select), c) check if you really need a lst.Select- c.f. [How to avoid using select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999), d)Dim stk, crnt, lst As Worksheetregards onlylst as worksheet because it is explicitly dim'd as worksheet, (stk, crnt` will be variants).

Please review your posted code and fix the required parts - I don't want to make any assumptions about what your actual code looks like.

@T.M. please can i send you my macro file to understand what i am trying to do if you accept sure

@TimWilliams hello ,i tried my effort to describe the problem by an easy way ,but i think i didn't , if you accept i can send to you my macro file and trying to make a contact together to trying to explain you what im trying to do,if you accept sure.

@anasboussib Please fix the required parts in your posted code first as Tim commented, i.e. edit your question - I won't accept any linked code. Furthermore I can't see any difference between the cited If statement and the code line in your sub procedure, they are identical.

Based on your sample file sent by mail, this worked for me.
Sub listing()
    
    Dim ttls As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook, stk As Worksheet, crnt As Worksheet, lst As Worksheet
    Dim lrStk As Long, lrLst As Long, i As Long, j As Long, crntCode, listRow As Long
    Dim arrStk
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set stk = wb.Sheets("stock")
    Set crnt = wb.Sheets("Tabelle1")
    Set lst = wb.Sheets("liste")
     
    lrStk = stk.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    lrCrnt = crnt.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'read all the stock data into an array
    arrStk = stk.Range("A2:E" & lrStk).Value
    
    listRow = 2 'start listing here
    
    'looping for the book item
    For i = 2 To lrCrnt
        crntCode = crnt.Cells(i, "E").Value
        For j = 1 To UBound(arrStk, 1) 'loop over array (faster)
            If crntCode = arrStk(j, 1) Then
                lst.Cells(listRow, "A").Resize(1, 3).Value = Array( _
                            arrStk(j, 1), arrStk(j, 5), arrStk(j, 4)) 'A,E,D
                listRow = listRow + 1 'next output row
            Else
                ttls = ttls + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Debug.Print "Completed"
    
End Sub

There are a lot of duplicated code in the "Tabelle1" sheet though, so you end up with duplicated entries in the output sheet.
